# How to convert to yyyy-MM-dd format for DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a MVC action method which accept 2 date parameters. I tried to use `.ToString` but it gives me this error:

> Returns the text representation of the value of the current
>   Nullable object.
>
> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

I need to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd` before pass it to the view. Otherwise, the textbox won't able to show the date value. Here is the code

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
{            
    ViewBag.DateFrom = dateFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: `dateFrom` is nullable, you should use `dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` or `dateFrom?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: You will also have to answer the question "What date do you want to display in the view, if the nullable date is actually null?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ToString` like that with a normal `DateTime`. However you have nullable `DateTime?` and that won't work.

Try `dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")`

Also be careful with `mm` (minutes) and `MM` (Months). I'm sure you need `MM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
{
    ViewBag.DateFrom = dateFrom?.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of the code?